# Pushing custome images to Azure ACR fails " Use of closed network connection "

Tags: azure, docker, github-actions, azure-container-registry

While learning how to use Azure Container Registry with the official tutorial : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-get-started-portal?tabs=azure-cli

I tried to push images to my registry, the Hello World image in the course works fine, but when i try to use my own images it fails. It also fails when i pull images from docker and try to push them to my Azure registry.

[image: Nginx image failed push]

Of course, the images are correctly tagged and the CLI connection works fine.

i'm also following another Azure course in which i build the image with Github actions ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/kubernetes-action ), it also works great on the repo of this course, but once i try with my own projects, it fails. This time the error is about the url / the credentials :

[image: Github action error]

After investigations, i'm sure that the credentials are correct, but the URL is maybe false because it never create it. That's why i was trying to push it manually in the first place.

EDIT : I managed to make it work by changing the wifi source i used, but i still don't understand how is this possible, why it doesn't work on github actions and what should i change in my conf to make it work with the original wifi again.

Answer (score 1):

***I tried to reproduce the same issue in my environment and got the below output***

***I have created the docker file and write the some script***

```
vi dockerfile

FROM httpd:2.4
COPY ./public-html/ /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/
```

***I have build the docker file using below command***

```
docker build -t my-apache2 .
```

[image]

***I have run the Image id using the below command***

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 image_id
```

[image]

***Created the container registry***

[image]

***After creating the registry we should enable the Access key if not we will not able to fetch the image to container instances***

[image]

***I have logged into the registry server***

```
docker login login_server
Username:XXXX
password:XXXXX
```

[image]

***After succeeded I have pushed the image into the container registry
I have tagged the image and pushed into the registry***

```
docker tag image_name login_server/image_name
docker push login_server/image_name
```

***Here we can find the image in repositories which we have pushed***

[image]

***I have created the container instance, while creating we have to give the Image resource as container registry then only we will get the pushed image***

[image]

Comment: I've followed all the steps, but the problem persist.
The docker push fails and i don't get to create the container instance, my image is never pushed to the repository

Comment: Thanks for the reply, can you please check your image is exist in your local or not, because if we do "docker images" it will show the images which we created but while pushing it will not pushed into the container instance, then we have delete the image and recreate it, then it will work.

Comment: It exists locally, i even managed to push it by connecting to another wifi, i'm still trying to understand why it worked with some images and failed with others with the original wifi
But for the github actions part, it still doesn't work. I went to the action source code, and from my understanding the command "az acr build .." return error "incorrect URL / bad credentials" which is weird because both URL and credentials are correct ( i've executed the bash step by step and checked them at every step )

Answer (score 1):

I met the exact same issue and didn't understood why.
Then I just logout from my VPN and it works.
Ain't got any explanations about this but I hope it could help people which are stuck.